# Why do I get "error: implicit declaration of function" when performing "make" on vmwgfx

Tags: makefile, vmware, fedora

I'm very close to have compiled the [VMWare guest GL driver](http://www.mesa3d.org/vmware-guest.html) on Fedora 23 64-bit (using latest Rawhide kernel), but I'm getting errors during "make":

```
$ cd $TOP/vmwgfx
$ make

make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-0.rc2.git2.2.fc24.x86_64/source  SUBDIRS=`/bin/pwd` DRMSRCDIR=`/bin/pwd` modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/4.4.0-0.rc2.git2.2.fc24.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /home/IRUser/github/vmwgfx/drm_lock.o
/home/IRUser/github/vmwgfx/drm_lock.c: In function ‘drm_lock’:
/home/IRUser/github/vmwgfx/drm_lock.c:124:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘block_all_signals’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   block_all_signals(drm_notifier, &dev->sigdata, &dev->sigmask);
   ^
/home/IRUser/github/vmwgfx/drm_lock.c: In function ‘drm_unlock’:
/home/IRUser/github/vmwgfx/drm_lock.c:183:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘unblock_all_signals’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  unblock_all_signals();
  ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/home/IRUser/github/vmwgfx/drm_lock.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/IRUser/github/vmwgfx/drm_lock.o] Error 1
Makefile:1388: recipe for target '_module_/home/IRUser/github/vmwgfx' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/IRUser/github/vmwgfx] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/4.4.0-0.rc2.git2.2.fc24.x86_64'
Makefile:139: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I'm not very familiar with Makefile and its syntax. What could be going on here?

Comment: Most likely your kernel CFLAGS configured to use `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` and `-Werror`, and this driver uses implicit declarations so it cannot be compiled with this flags. Check your `.config` in kernel sources directory.

Comment: Hm, I don't think so: `$ cat /usr/src/kernels/4.4.0-0.rc2.git2.2.fc24.x86_64/.config | grep CFLAGS` gives me `CONFIG_ARCH_HWEIGHT_CFLAGS="-fcall-saved-rdi -fcall-saved-rsi -fcall-saved-rdx -fcall-saved-rcx -fcall-saved-r8 -fcall-saved-r9 -fcall-saved-r10 -fcall-saved-r11"`

Comment: Yeah I probably was wrong, it's `Makefile` in kernel directory. Mine have `-Werror-implicit-function-declaration` too, so it probably was added in later kernel versions as default. But anyway, I'm not getting an error, and `block_all_signals` is declared in `sched.h` without any problem. Don't have kernel 4.4 (only 4.3) to test it out though, try grepping `block_all_signals` in `include/linux/sched.h`, it probably was removed.

Comment: Yes, `block_all_signals` is removed in `include/linux/sched.h`. What would you suggest I do?

Comment: Use 4.3 or wait till driver gets updated for 4.4 (submit a bug, ask a developer, etc.). Depending on how much have changed it may not be an easy task.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm unfamiliar with installing/updating kernels. In case you have the time; I can't figure out how to install the 4.3 kernel, I just get the latest from Rawhide. Posted a (newbie) question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1006249/how-can-i-install-kernel-4-3-in-fedora-23-workstation-64-bit).

Comment: I don't use fedora so can't help with that, sorry. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to install the 4.3 kernel, not the 4.4 kernel.